# How can I load react in javascript files without nodeJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Is there a way to load the react file inside Javascript files? 
>   No library and no nodeJs

my code   :

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
import React from './react.development.js';
import ReactDom from './react-dom.development.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CDN links](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) to acquire React and ReactDOM:

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

No need to import React, and ReactDOM, since they are now globally available.